# Issue to send mail with JQuery/Php in Bootstrap Twitter

Tags: php, jquery

I've one problem to send a mail with JQuery and Php. I'm using bootstrap twitter and here is my form :

```
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModalContactPage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button id="btnSendMail" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">Send message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here the JQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnSendMail").click(function(){
        var email = $("#recipient-name").val();
        var message = $("#message-text").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and then the extern Php page :

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

//send email
    mail("borgiesfranco@gmail.com", "test" .$email, $message);
}
?>
```

I'don't see what's wrong with this code... and when I click on Send button, nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: data is not properly declared

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "email.php",
                data: {email:email,message:message},// send data like this then use post to receive it
                success: function(msg){
                    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);//use echoed msg here
                }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Jquery step is not good.
Your need to put your paramameters.

```
   data = {
       'email'     : $("#recipient-name").val(), 
       'message '  : $("#message-text").val()
   };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "email.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
```

http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnSendMail").click(function(){
        var email = $("#recipient-name").val();
        var message = $("#message-text").val();
   var data = {email:email,message:message}; //You missed this
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```